# VSTO AddIn Deployment - Can I create single file?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, vsto

Quick question - I've finished building an outlook add-in in VS2010, .NET 4.0.  I was hoping to deploy it as a single file, as opposed to the collection of files that are in the bin folder.  Is there a way to build it as a single file, or any other suggestions on the easiest way to deploy it to multiple users?

Thanks a lot - KCross

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to deploy a vsto add-in is using clickonce. For more advanced scenarios it is possible to build a msi package with a vs setup project or wix.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386179.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I only have experience with Excel, but as far as I know, you need to have a .vsto manifest as well as a .dll, so that pretty much rules out the 'one file' idea. There are likely some files that are not necessary and could be trimmed out (.pdb's come readily to mind), but I think the best approach is NOT to try to squeeze it together as much as possible. Instead, use an installer that can do all the necessary setup for you.